# Trying to start eureka and config server with docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, netflix-eureka

I'm a new learner of docker. Trying to start the eureka server and configure the server but the config server gives an error: `Cannot execute the request on any known server at` and due to this error I can't start other microservice.

application.yml(eureka service)

```
server:
 port: 5002
  
eureka:
 client:
  service-url:
   defaultZone: http://localhost:5002/eureka/
  register-with-eureka: false
  fetch-registry: false
```

application.yml(config microservice)

```
server:
 port: 9095


spring:
  application:
   name: config-server


profiles:
 active:
 - native

cloud:
 config:
  server:
    native:
      search-locations:
      - classpath:/
       
 eureka:
  instance:
   hostname: localhost
   port: 5002
  client:
   register-with-eureka: true
   fetch-registry: true
   service-url:
    defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.port}/eureka/
```

and having two separate dockerfiles for the same in which **FROM, ADD, EXPOSE, ENTRYPOINT** is used

Comment: Are you not using docker-compose?

Comment: You should consider adding which eureka, which config server you are using, how you pack them in docker (or docker-compose), how you run them and what you are expecting to see

Comment: You can refer this article to create eureka and config services and dockerize them using docker compose. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/28/spring-microservices-docker

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue. Config-server is not registered with eureka

Comment: It's basically giving me an error that unknown hostname to I tried to put both services in the same network and config server registered with eureka but the next microservice gives me an error related to illegal service id i.e feign client error which is configured in config microservice. can you please help me with this?

Comment: It's solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using localhost. If you build a docker image and run it when you say localhost docker will think you are referring to the same docker container in case you are running these 2 services in 2 different containers. Expose them through ngrok (free) and update your configs.